# Is the $L^p$ norm bounded by the $L^\infty$ norm on a bounded space?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Consider the $L^p$ norm defined on some bounded open subset $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ with $p>1$. Does there exist a constant $c$ such that
$$\Vert f\Vert_{L_p(\Omega)} \le c\Vert f\Vert_{L_\infty(\Omega)}
$$
for any function $f\in L_\infty(\Omega)$?

I think this is similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259066/is-there-anyway-to-bound-the-l-infty-norm-by-other-lp-norm), but the inequality is reversed and I am considering the norms over a bounded domain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$\int_{\Omega}|f|^p \le \int_{\Omega}||f||_{\infty}^p = m(\Omega) ||f||_{\infty}^p$$
hence, taking $p$-th roots,
$$||f||_p \le m(\Omega)^{1/p} ||f||_{\infty}$$

Finally, $c=m(\Omega)^{1/p}$ is optimal, since the inequality becomes an equality for constant function $f$.